# The inequality formula for proving $x^2$ is continuous over a fixed finite interval $[a, b]$

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity

In  Courant's Intro to Calculus and Analysis I, there's discussion of $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous over a fixed finite interval [a, b].

It's written as:
$|f(x) - f(x_{0})| = |x^2 - x_{0}^2| = |x - x_{0}||x + x_{0}| \leqslant 2|x - x_{0}|(|b|+|a|) < 2 \sigma(|b| + |a|) < 2 \epsilon$

I have no clue which inequality theorem(s) that the author used to show:

1. $|x - x_{0}||x + x_{0}| \leqslant 2|x - x_{0}|(|b|+|a|)$
2. $2|x - x_{0}|(|b|+|a|) < 2 \sigma(|b| + |a|) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad. 1.
$$ |x+x_0| \le |x|+|x_0|, \qquad (\text{triangle inequality}) $$
since $x,x_0\in[a,b]$ then
$$ |x|,|x_0| \le \max\{|a|,|b|\} \le |a|+|b|$$

Ad. 2.

To investigate continuity, we investigate points that are close to each other, where "close" means that $$|x-x_0| < \sigma$$ 
for some small $\sigma$. What was shown in the proof is that if $$|x-x_0| \le \sigma := \frac{\epsilon}{|b|+|a|} $$
then $$ |f(x)-f(x_0)| \le 2\epsilon$$
That actualy proves not only continuity but also uniform continuity, because $\sigma$ is independent of $x$ and $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you professor, I got it.